# R substitute how to express O^\prime\Sigma O

Tags: r, substitution

Could anybody tell me how to use substitute function and paste in R to express
N(0,O^\prime\Sigma,O)

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what is "N()"?

Comment: just normal distribution. I just want to express the string in titles of R pictures

Comment: The string   N(0, O^\prime \Sigma O)

Comment: oh thanks a lot to add the picture!

Answer (score 3):

It's is pretty much standard `?plotmath` stuff. The only "trick" is to use the single apostrophe for the prime mark. For example...

```
plot(1, 1, main=expression(N(0,O*"'"*Sigma,O)))
```

Comment: also "\u0027" for apostrophe, or "\u00B4" for a bit more slanted one

Comment: Perhaps: `expression(italic(N)(0,italic(O*"'")*Sigma*italic(O)))` or even `expression(Nu(0,italic(O*"'")*Sigma*italic(O))))`